# If U be a family ofopen P- nul setsl in Borel sigmafield in R^n then P(union of U)=0.

Tags: measure-theory

I have seen this problem in my measuretheoretic probability class note but I can not do this .
Let P be a probability measure on (R^n,**B**R^n) and *U* a family of open P null sets , then , P( ∪*U* )=0

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb R^{n}$ is separable metric space. Hence it is second countable and any union of open  sets in it can be expressed as a countable union of some subfamily. From this the conclusion is obvious.

Comment: please do this in measuretheory .

Comment: This question requires topological ideas. Measure theory cannot handle uncountable unions. If you know that any Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R^{n}$ is regular then I can give another proof. @Totyandas